# monitor pfSense with nagios

Tags: pfsense, system-monitoring, nagios

I have pFsense machine and one nagios(NagiosXI) installed machine. On pfSense machine DHCP server is running.

I want to monitor pfSense i.e DHCP status and interface through nagios using SNMP.

I have added pfSense in Nagios and it is showing CPU usage,swap,memory etc. I want to know how do I monitor interface? How do I monitor  status of DHCP?

Also i have written rules what request is coming from outside?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 4):

OK.

Click on Services->SNMP, enable the SNMP server, set a community string, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: Done please check..

Answer (score 0):

Nrpe is a package available in pfsense now. Add the nrpe package and configure the appropriate fields. Don't forget to open the nrpe port on your firewall rules for the WAN (or whatever interface you monitor on)

Answer (score 0):

I use Nagios (thruk) SNMP and NRPE. For interfaces (Upload/Download stat) i have used custom plugin.  http://nagios.manubulon.com/snmp_int.html

[i use snmp + nrpe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TAPM.png)